# Poylmer app shell and lazy loading

Tags: polymer

I have a projet setup similar to the Polymer shop-app. To reduce thr code base in the app itself, I splitted the hole main page layout into an separete element project. The project has an element `Layout` which loads 7 of its Dependencys lazy:

```
_pageLoaded: function (shouldResetLayout) {
            this._ensureLazyLoaded();
...
}
 _ensureLazyLoaded: function () {
      if (!this.loadComplete) {
       Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender(this, function () {
           this.importHref(this.resolveUrl('lazy-resources.html'), function () {
                        this.loadComplete = true;
                    }, null, true);
       });
     }
 },
```

Basically the same logic as the Shop-app exmaple.`_pageLoaded` is an observer of the two-way data bound page property of my Shop-app.

In my Shop-app itself, I include the `layout` element like so:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/lc-app-layout/lc-app-layout.html">

<lc-app-layout categories="[[categories]]" page="[[page]]" category-name="{{categoryName}}">
        <iron-pages role="main" selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" selected-attribute="visible">
            <!-- home view -->
            <shop-home name="home" categories="[[categories]]"></shop-home>
            <!-- list view of items in a category -->
            <shop-list name="list" route="[[subroute]]" offline="[[offline]]" query-Params="[[queryParams]]"></shop-list>
            <!-- detail view of one item -->
            <shop-detail name="detail" route="[[subroute]]" offline="[[offline]]"></shop-detail>
        </iron-pages>
    </lc-app-layout>
```

And also have some lazy ressources in the app itself, which are loaded the same way as in the `layout`.

Now when I want to build everythin, I need to add the `lazy-resurces` of the `layout` element as an fragment to the `Polymer.json` so that the analyser will find the it's dependencys:

```
"fragments": [
"src/view/list/shop-list.html",
"src/view/detail/shop-detail.html",
"src/lazy-resources.html",
"bower_components/lc-app-layout/lazy-resources.html"
```

No when I serve this build, the page doesn't load most of the times. It shows error like:

```
Cannot read property '_makeReady' of undefined
Polymer is not a function
Cannot read property 'isDescendant' of undefined
```

When I throttle the network speed, chances are higher that everythin will load up. So I assume there is some timing issue in the asynchronous ImportHref or something like that. Or am I just missusing the fragments to tell the analyzer to scan my laczy resources of the `layout` element?

I'm using Polymer-CLI 0.18.0. Runnig the app with `polymer serve` does work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem by moving the lazy loading from `layout` element to the lazy-ressource of the Shop-app.